# Add a symbol after every word in a string

Tags: php, regex, replace, cpu-word

Given a string, I want an array of strings containing words, each preceded by any non-word characters.

**Example input string:**

`one "two" (three) -four-`

The words in the string may be anything, even gibberish, with any amount of punctuation or symbols.

**What I would like to see:**

```
array:
one
 "two
" (three
) -four
-
```

Essentially, for each match the last thing is a word, preceded by anything left over from the previous match.

I will be using this in PHP. I have tried various combinations of `preg_match_all()` and `preg_split()`, with patterns containing many variations of "\w", "\b", "[^\w]" and so on.

**The Bigger Picture**

How can I place a * after each word in the string for searching purposes?

Comment: In your *what I would like to see* part, is the quote after `four` supposed to be on the next line?

Comment: You are correct, the quotes seem to have been altered when I posted, I have fixed it now, hopefully they got through correctly this time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want to add an asterisk after each "word" you could do this:

```
<?php
$test = 'one "two" (three) -four-';

echo preg_replace('/(\w+)/', "$1*", $test);
?>
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8nr-bpb

Comment: This also works splendidly! I will probably use this one as it saves me from subsequently looping through the matches.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a negative lookahead to split on word boundaries, like this:

```
$array = preg_split( '/(?!\w)\b/', 'one "two" (three) -four-');
```

A `print_r( $array);` [gives you](http://viper-7.com/jxZai4) the exact output desired:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] =>  "two
    [2] => " (three
    [3] => ) -four
    [4] => -
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of how to find a word with regex in PHP.

```
<?php
    $subject = "abcdef";
    $pattern = '/^def/';
    preg_match($pattern, substr($subject, 3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: This answer appears to completely ignore the question requirements and sample data.

Answer (score -1):

#### An alternative

```
[^\w]*(\b\w*\b)?
----- ----------
 |        |
 |        |-> Matches a word 0 or 1 time
 |-> Matches 0 to many characters except [a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

You need to match!

Comment: This snippet which implies the use of `preg_match_all()` erroneously returns empty strings in the matches array. https://3v4l.org/aW64G

Answer (score -1):

> "*How can I place a * after each word in the string for searching purposes?*"

You don't need to capture anything or use backreferences.  Match one or more word characters, then forget what you matched with `\K`.  The zero-width position is where you inject your asterisk.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GMEbI))

```
$test = 'one "two" (three) -four-';

echo preg_replace('/\w+\K/', '*', $test);
```

The advice remains if you want to split the string. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/mPrN2)

```
var_export(
    preg_split('/\w+\K/', $test)
);
```

---

As an extension of the requirements to show how word boundaries work...

- `var_export(preg_split('/\b/', $test));` will split before and after each sequence of word characters. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/vUiRk)
- `echo preg_replace('/\b/', '*', $test);` will add an asterisks before and after each sequence of word characters. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/2tgAH)

Comment: This provably correct answer should not have a negative score. I'd love to read the justification for the dv.